# Why is community being Robot here?

Tags: discussion

I just asked a question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83622/how-good-is-bifrost-bridge-in-comparison-with-star-trek-transporters

Everyone can understand what I am asking and by no way it's conflicting with in-universe canon rules even if I have used words from other canon. Those words are quite popular in the sci-fi world, too.

By no means, Star Trek is involved here. And, everyone knows that. Why do you need to scan words like robots?

**The purpose of this meta question is community awareness. Don't be a robot to scan words. To all who agreed with question's closure: Ask yourself (don't give arguments), is the question not clear? Is the question really opinion-based?**

Comment: We were more than willing to edit your question to bring it back on-topic and get you the answer you want, why do you refuse to let us?

Comment: @Michael This isn't about one question. The thing is why community being d**k here..

Comment: Yes, we're all d**k's for trying to help you get your question opened.

Comment: @Michael The purpose of this meta question is to make people flexible. You know very well what the question is saying and you don't need to involve Star Trek here. Then, why this?

Comment: *You're* the one insisting on Star Trek being involved. You put it in the question and won't budge on removing it despite it being almost completely unnecessary - and only serving to confuse the question.

Comment: @phantom42 No, you're trying to clarify an already clear question for formalities. This is where I am hitting. This isn't about one question.

Comment: @Michael Do you know what you just did scan words like a robot... Ask yourself that you understood that question or not.

Comment: You *do* realize that Michael and I are the ones who are actually *backing* you on the question actually being on topic, right? If anything, we are exactly the ones *not* "scanning words like a robot". Obviously, some people don't see it as being clear enough and offered to help. You don't want the help because... well, whatever your reason is. Seems to me that you're the one acting like a robot here.

Comment: @Michael Not again. Your argument is simply robotic. As a human, you won't say that.

Comment: I give up. You clearly don't want your questions answered, you just want to insult others and pick fights.

Comment: @Michael Haha. It's just community awareness. In the end, I'll remove Star Trek from the question if community doesn't accept flexibility.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has said they're not looking for discussion, just a place to rant.

Answer (score 21):

According to you, in your own words:

> By no means, Star Trek is involved here. And, everyone knows that

And yet, your question title is

> How good is Bifrost Bridge in comparison with Star Trek transporters?

As far as I can tell, there are two options:

1. You are asking for a comparison between transport technologies from two different universes, which is off-topic and will be closed.
2. You are asking about the transport technology from *Thor*, in which case the Star Trek reference is incidental, and its presence in the title is just causing confusion.

I think we're all willing to accept that the right answer is #2. You are not asking for a comparison between the two, you are asking for a specific capability of the Bifrost. That's fine. As written, the question is just easily misinterpreted as an X vs Y question, but with a bit of clarification, it becomes a good question. But, when someone comes along and helpfully edits your question to get it reopened, *you just rolled it back*.

The fact that you insist on forcing the Star Trek comparison into your question, when you admit yourself that it's not needed, is making your question demonstrably worse and preventing you from getting answers to what could be really good questions.