# KutuluMike (Michael Edenfield) has passed away

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[KutuluMike](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2816/kutulumike) (known to some as Michael Edenfield) passed away.

[image: profile for KutuluMike at Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange, Q&A for science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts]

I don't have a lot of details. A few people noticed he had been MIA from things for over a month. We reached out and learned he had been in the hospital for 45 days with something called CMV virus, which he was at high risk for because of the lung transplant he received last year. The last we officially heard from him was he was recovering and expecting to leave the hospital. He was 43 years old.

> [image: A facebook post by one of Mike's relatives, transcribed below]
>
> I want to thank everyone for their prayers. Please continue to keep my family in your thoughts and prayers as we go through this. My brother Michael passed away last night.

Comment: R.I.P. Mike :'(

Comment: The only thing we _really_ know for sure is Mike willed all his rep over to me just before he passed away.

Comment: He was a good dude. Terrible news.

Comment: @JackBNimble Account merging because of a will?  Actually this could work, if the staff would allow it...

Answer (score 64):

Too soon. Far, far too soon. 43 years old? Shit.

For those who aren't familiar with Mike on-site (he became less active in recent years): as well as his Q&A activity getting him to almost 100,000 rep (at the time of writing), he was also one of the most active users in back-end site upkeep stuff, thankless tasks such as ...

- Organising the great tag cleanup of 2015-16: [Would we be interested in a concerted tag cleanup effort?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7761/31394) and [Tag Wars Episode I: Harry Potter and the Tag Cleanup](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7871/31394) and [Tag Wars: The Science Fiction/Fantasy Tag Cleanup Event](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7896/31394)
- Further work on tagging policies: [What is the correct usage of individual works tags vs. author tags vs. franchise tags?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7923/31394) and [Science Fiction and Fantasy Tagging Guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7974/31394) He became famous on the site for his thankless work on the tagging system.
- Drafting or igniting discussion on some of our most important site policies: [Are *all* list questions off-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2638/31394) and [Gorilla vs. Shark - a Longer Explanation](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7003/31394) and [What is our actual policy on science questions?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7364/31394) It could be said that all of our site's custom close reasons are thanks to him.
- Helping to manage the site blog after Stack Exchange stopped supporting blogs: [What should we call our blog?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10267/31394) and [Look and feel of the new blog](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10274/31394) and [Official Unofficial Blog Support Post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10617/31394) Jack B. Nimble (the OP of this meta post) has been in charge of the blog for years, and CreationEdge (who deleted his SE account) hosts the new domain, but Mike valiantly volunteered to join the blog team.

Let his achievements live on in perpetuity. R.I.P.

Answer (score 31):

I cannot say that I knew Mike well, but I knew him as he was here on the site and in chat.

All I can say is that his presence will be sorely missed, and I would like to extend this Stack's warm wishes to his family and other loved ones.

Answer (score 29):

I got to know Mike best in a slack group he had set up a few years ago for some site members to chat together. I'm sure some of the older users knew him a lot better than me, but all the interactions I can remember having with him were positive. He will be missed.

[image]

Comment: Kills me everytime I see that.

Answer (score 26):

Mike was one of the reasons why I enjoyed posting on this site so much! In my early days (2013), seeing his posts that were so well-written and insightful inspired me to post better and actually put effort into this site.

We even had a small rivalry to see who could post faster/better as we were both interested in similar works.

His hard work and dedication payed off as you can see the difference in our Rep. But it's the [thankless hard work](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13083/21267) that he did that I'm most thankful for him doing.

He was interested in not only providing good content for this community, but also looking after its progress and guiding it to become what it is today! I have no idea how he didn't become [moderator](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/4#post-115427), but it's good to see that he continued to look after this community in whatever capacity he could!

Rest In Piece Mike. You fought and battled but now you can rest!

Comment: "it's the thankless hard work that he did that I'm most thankful for him doing" Well said. Mike was an example and an inspiration.

Comment: @Shog9 Good of you to stop by, I'm sure you know that we recognise your appreciation for him :)

Comment: @Shog9 On an unrelated note, I never got a chance to say bye and thanks to you, if you're up for it, let's chat off-site: invites@kutulu.org

Answer (score 19):

Mike was a great supporter of the blog. He [contributed a lot of articles](https://thesffblog.com/author/kutulumike/). The ones I think that stand out are:

- [A Guide to the Marvel Cinematic Multiverse](https://thesffblog.com/2016/05/a-guide-to-the-marvel-cinematic-multiverse/)
- [A Guide To The DC Cinematic Multiverse](https://thesffblog.com/2015/11/a-guide-to-the-dc-cinematic-multiverse/)
- [Gorilla vs. Shark? Not so fast…](https://thesffblog.com/2015/06/gorilla-vs-shark-not-so-fast/)

Answer (score 14):

In reference to his [namesake](https://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/cc.aspx):

> That is not dead which can eternal lie,
>
> And with strange aeons even death may die.

Answer (score 5):

I am at loss of words. Although we weren't at the same page on this site (see [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6707/how-can-this-question-be-duplicate-also-please-revoke-diamond-status-of-keen) and [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6703/why-is-community-being-robot-here)), I can feel the loss. No story is complete without enemies. I hope I contributed even a little to make his story (a part of which will always live on this site and in us) complete.

> Most have been forgotten. Most deserve to be forgotten. The heroes will always be remembered. The best. The best and the worst. And a few who were a bit of both.
>
> *-* George R.R. Martin, A Feast for Crows (A Song of Ice and Fire, #4)