# Who is getting Swag?

Tags: discussion, swag

On the main meta, there is a [post about swag returning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back?cb=1). Who is getting what swag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have no users who have 'recently' gone up to 250k+, but we doe have a handful who have now reached 100k.

> Those who earned 100K [since march 2019] will receive:
>
> - Branded T-shirt (SE or SO)
> - Stickers (either SE or SO)
> - Branded socks (SE or SO) - two styles available, you’ll get one selected randomly

This includes:

- [TheLethalCarrot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58193/thelethalcarrot)
- [11.01.11](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931/11-01-11)
- [Praxis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40294/praxis)
- [Adamant](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51379/adamant)
- [Jeff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/656/jeff)
- [Tango](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1693/tango)
- [KutuluMike](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2816/kutulumike)*
- [FuzzyBoots](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/23243/fuzzyboots)
- [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394/rand-althor)
- [Jack B Nimble](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1148/jack-b-nimble)

The moderators also get some swag:

> All moderators will receive:
>
> - Moderator diamond hat
> - T-shirt (SO or SE)
> - Stickers (SO or SE)
> - Water bottle or tumbler

Moderators are [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

Some people are yet to receive swag from "Stuff-a-way!", to see if you ever posted on that meta, look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A321399+user%3Ame).

> We have a list of those folks and we're ready to send you the
> following items:
>
> - SE socks - two styles available, you’ll get one selected randomly
> - SE T-shirt
> - Branded webcam cover
> - SE pop socket
> - Branded pen

When your swag arrives, feel free to post them as answers, or comments below!

<sub>* [sadly no longer with us](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13081/3804)</sub>

Comment: @Randal'Thor https://stackexchange.com/leagues/186/month/scifi/2019-03-01 says you were over 100k by their cut off, but let us know if you get swag!

Comment: That query (like the network reputation graphs) doesn't take account of the November 2019 rep recalc. I [just got clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358563/278659) that they won't disenfranchise the people who broke 100k after March 2019 but the retroactive recalc says they broke it before. (Jack B Nimble should also be added to your list with me and FuzzyBoots.)

Comment: @Rand Interesting!